# Winform can not add elementHost

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In one of my VS projects, after I created a new Winform, I was not able to add an elementHost into it, and the following message showed up:

[image]

I can add buttons or other components from the toolbar.
If I create a new project, everything works, but I still cannot use it in my old project.

I have tried to restart VS or copy elementHost code into Winform, but nothing changed.

Comment: Do you mean you get this error when using the _WinForms Designer_?

Comment: Have you tried to clean everything? Close VS, delete bin/obj, and all the intermediate files?

Comment: @MickyD yes, its in the designer

Comment: @kennyzx I haven't tried cleaning everything yet

Comment: Do you have any dependencies in the form constructor? If so, you have to call/use them only at runtime not design time.

Comment: @MihailStancescu do you mean the form constructor itself? No, I just used the default form constructor.